# Is there a way to target a tags with img inside?

Tags: jquery, css

I need to target `a` tags with `img` inside them. Can I do this through css or do I have to use jQuery?

---

*additional info from comment*

I set `a:hover { border-bottom:1px dotted #fff }` but I don't want the border to apply to a tags with `img` inside them.

Comment: I set `a:hover { border-bottom:1px dotted #fff }` but I don't want the border to apply to `a` tags with `img` inside them.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that with CSS alone.

Comment: Well, I'm sure you'll get an answer here, but you should just apply a class to the `a` elements containing an `img`. `<a class="imgHolder"><img /></a>` + `a:hover { border: 1px .. }` + `.imgHolder:hover { border: 0 }`.

Comment: @thirtydot: You should post your solution now that we know the actual question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no :has in css. In jQuery you can do

```
$("a:has(img)")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this cannot be done with CSS unless you're willing to mark the `a` tags with a class or something similar.

Using jQuery, you can do something like this to match `a` tags that have `img` tags as direct children.

```
$('img').parent('a')
```

If you want to allow the `img` to be any descendant, you can use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.

```
$('a:has(img)')
```

Answer (score 0):

May have misunderstood you, but do you mean this?

```
HTML: <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>

CSS:  #container a { border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc; }
      #container a img { border: 0 !important; }
```

This removes borders from images inheriting `<a>` borders if set. Since you mentioned hover...

```
#container a img:hover { border: 0 !important; }
```